# Is there an automatic way to memoise global polymorphic values in Haskell?

Tags: haskell, memoization, parametric-polymorphism

Polymorphic "constants", like `5 :: Num a => a`, aren't really constants but functions of a dictionary argument. Hence, if you define

```
primes :: Num n => [n]
primes = ...
```

<sup>Bad example of course, there's no good reason here to have it polymorphic... what I'm really interested is if you try to globally memoise a nontrivial polymorphic function, with e.g. `memo-trie`s.</sup>
then this sequence won't be shared between calls from different sites, which isn't nice in terms of performance. (Isn't this the main reason the Haskell standard blessed us with the Dreaded Monomorphism Restriction?)

The only way I can see how to enforce sharing is to have a monomorphic "tag" sitting around for every instance of the constraining class. E.g.

```
erastothenes :: Num n => [n]
erastothenes = ...

class (Num n) => HasPrimes n where
  -- | @'primes' ≡ 'erastothenes'@
  primes :: [n]

integerPrimes :: [Integer]
integerPrimes = erastothenes

instance HasPrimes Integer where
  primes = integerPrimes
```

... which isn't nice in terms of elegance.

Is there any nicer way to implement such a memoisation?

Comment: Maybe `SPECIALIZE` pragmas work? You'd still have to list the types you want to specialize for explicitely, though.

Comment: @bennofs: if `SPECIALIZE` can be made to work reliably for this purpose, than this would actually seem the most elegant way to me. If you make an example implementation, I'd accept that answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you enable `ConstraintKinds` and `ExistentialQuantification` (or `GADTs`) you can reify type class dictionaries:

```
{-# LANGUAGE ConstraintKinds, ExistentialQuantification #-}

data Dict a = a => Dict
```

If we try this out

```
fibs :: Num n => [n]
fibs = 1 : 1 : zipWith (+) fibs (drop 1 fibs)

fibs' :: [Integer]
fibs' = fibs


fibsWithDict :: Dict (Num n) -> [n]
fibsWithDict Dict = fs
  where
    fs = 1 : 1 : zipWith (+) fs (drop 1 fs)

fibs'' :: [Integer]
fibs'' = fibsWithDict Dict
```

in GHCi we see

```
λ> :set +s
λ> 
λ> fibs !! 29
832040
(2.66 secs, 721235304 bytes)
λ> 
λ> fibs !! 29
832040
(2.52 secs, 714054736 bytes)
λ> 
λ> 
λ> fibs' !! 29
832040
(2.67 secs, 713510568 bytes)
λ> 
λ> fibs' !! 29
832040
(0.00 secs, 1034296 bytes)
λ> 
λ> 
λ> fibs'' !! 29
832040
(0.00 secs, 1032624 bytes)
```

So `fibs''` is the only implementation of the three that immediately memoizes.

Note that we have to pattern match on the `Dict` constructor. Otherwise, we will get an error about `n` not being constrained to have a `Num` instance (like you would expect if our signature was just `fibsWithDict :: a -> [n]`).

This is a full solution since you can consider `fibsWithDict Dict` to be an expression that memoizes immediately at any type you throw at it (as long as it's an instance of `Num`). For example:

```
λ> (fibsWithDict Dict !! 29) :: Double
832040.0
(0.00 secs, 1028384 bytes)
```

EDIT: It looks like this explicit dictionary passing isn't necessary here and can be done implicitly by using `ScopedTypeVariables` with a local binding:

```
{-# LANGUAGE ScopedTypeVariables #-}

fibsImplicitDict :: forall a. Num a => [a]
fibsImplicitDict
  = let fs :: [a]
        fs = 1 : 1 : zipWith (+) fs (drop 1 fs)
    in
    fs
```

(Thanks to bennofs for the insight here!)

Comment: How is `fibs''` polymorphic?  The question specifically mentions global *polymorphic* values.  Worst answer ever accepted. :P

Comment: @BoydStephenSmithJr. You're right, `fibs''` *isn't* polymorphic. `fibsWithDict`, on the other hand, *is* polymorphic with none of the runtime cost that is typically associated with type class polymorphism.

Comment: @BoydStephenSmithJr. The last example in my answer (which is run in a new GHCi session) demonstrates this. You can constrain `fibsWithDict` to be any type that is an instance of `Num` with no overhead. Contrast this behavior with that of `fibs`, which has a very noticeable slowdown due to the internal dictionary passing preventing memorization. By making the dictionary passing explicit and passing it at a key point in the code, we can avoid this cost.

Comment: @BoydStephenSmithJr.: I accepted the answer because it offers a _slightly_ nicer version of implementing the "monomorphic tag" solution I already outlined in the question, and making this nicer was one possible answer. I'm not really happy with this, but it's better than "_it's not possible_" or "_throw in a `Typeable` and 300 extra lines of code_".

Comment: Note: If you change `fibs` to `fibs = let fs = 1 : 1 : zipWith (+) fibs (drop 1 fs) in fs`, `fibs'` is also memoized. I think the reason is just that `fibs` does polymorphic recursion, whereas `fibsWithDict` uses a local binding that is monomorphic after GHC inlined `fibsWithDict`.

Comment: @bennofs It looks like, in that definition, `fs` is specialized to `[Integer]`. I notice that if I give it an explicit `fs :: Num a => [a]` type signature, it doesn't memoize on the first use like `fibsWithDict` does. However if I enable `ScopedTypeVariables` and say `fibs :: forall a. Num a => [a]; fibs = let fs :: [a]; fs = ...` it does seem to have the same memoization properties as `fibsWithDict` while retaining the internal generality. I think this is because it tells GHC to implicitly pass the dictionary in the way that I was explicitly passing it with `fibsWithDict`. I updated my answer

Answer (score 9):

It's fairly impossible for a fairly technical reasons.  Type classes are open so, the polymorphic constant can't at compile time necessarily "see" how many types satisfy the constraint so it can't allocate that many monomorphic thunks.  On the other side, a type class certainly can't see all the possible constants that it might generate, so the monomorphic thunks cannot be allocated in the type class dictionary.

You will have to explicitly mention any types at which you want a monomorphic thunk allocated.

Comment: Indeed, recursion can give rise to infinitely many instances. `instance Num a => Num (Identity a) where ....`

Answer (score 6):

One could add `Typeable` constraint to `n` and use a different memoization table for every ground type `n`. You probably would need to exploit `Dynamic` and `cast` a lot for this, which is suboptimal. It also feels a bit hackish, too.

In a dependently typed language, of course, one can model a map `(n : Num) -> [n]` which would not require the `casts`s from `Dynamic`. Maybe something like that can be simulated exploiting GADTs and some kind of reification machinery.