# reuse/memoization of global polymorphic (class) values in Haskell

Tags: haskell, polymorphism, memoization

I'm concerned with if and when a polymorphic "global" *class value* is shared/memoized, particularly across module boundaries.  I have read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3951012/when-is-memoization-automatic-in-ghc-haskell) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25057803/is-there-an-automatic-way-to-memoise-global-polymorphic-values-in-haskell), but they don't quite seem to reflect my situation, and I'm seeing some different behavior from what one might expect from the answers.

Consider a class that exposes a value that can be expensive to compute:

```
{-# LANGUAGE FlexibleInstances, UndecidableInstances #-}

module A

import Debug.Trace

class Costly a where
  costly :: a

instance Num i => Costly i where
  -- an expensive (but non-recursive) computation
  costly = trace "costly!" $ (repeat 1) !! 10000000

foo :: Int
foo = costly + 1

costlyInt :: Int
costlyInt = costly
```

And a separate module:

```
module B
import A

bar :: Int
bar = costly + 2

main = do
  print foo
  print bar
  print costlyInt
  print costlyInt
```

Running `main` yields two separate evaluations of `costly` (as indicated by the trace): one for `foo`, and one for `bar`.  I know that `costlyInt` just returns the (evaluated) `costly` from `foo`, because if I remove `print foo` from `main` then the first `costlyInt` becomes costly.  (I can also cause `costlyInt` to perform a separate evaluation no matter what, by generalizing the type of `foo` to `Num a => a`.)

I think I know why this behavior happens: the instance of `Costly` is effectively a function that takes a `Num` dictionary and generates a `Costly` dictionary.  So when compiling `bar` and resolving the reference to `costly`, ghc generates a fresh `Costly` dictionary, which has an expensive thunk in it.  Question 1: am I correct about this?

There are a few ways to cause just one evaluation of `costly`, including:

- Put everything in one module.
- Remove the `Num i` instance constraint and just define a `Costly Int` instance.

Unfortunately, the analogs of these solutions are not feasible in my program -- I have several modules that use the class value in its polymorphic form, and only in the top-level source file are concrete types finally used.

There are also changes that *don't* reduce the number of evaluations, such as:

- Using INLINE, INLINABLE, or NOINLINE on the `costly` definition in the instance.  (I didn't expect this to work, but hey, worth a shot.)
- Using a `SPECIALIZE instance Costly Int` pragma in the instance definition.

The latter is surprising to me -- I'd expected it to be essentially equivalent to the second item above that *did* work.  That is, I thought it would generate a special `Costly Int` dictionary, which all of `foo`, `bar`, and `costlyInt` would share.  My question 2: what am I missing here?

My final question: is there any relatively simple and foolproof way to get what I want, i.e., all references to `costly` of a particular concrete type being shared across modules?  From what I've seen so far, I suspect the answer is no, but I'm still holding out hope.

Comment: How exactly is this question different from [my earlier one](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25057803/is-there-an-automatic-way-to-memoise-global-polymorphic-values-in-haskell)?

Comment: From what I can tell, the costliness in your question comes from recursion combined with dictionary passing, which causes exponential reevaluation. Once the latter is fixed, the computation itself is fast. But if two modules referred to fibsImplicitDict, they'd get different thunks that would be evaluated separately. I can't afford that, because my computation is inherently expensive (not due to recursion).

Comment: PS -- the fact that there are class instances with constraints on them is also playing a role here, it seems.

Comment: Do you need to use a type class here? If it only has the one instance, you shouldn't need it.

Comment: In my real program, yes -- I have many instances.  Costly represents a ring that has roots of unity, and I have instances for complex numbers, integers mod q, finite fields, etc.  Their roots of unity aren't cheap enough to recompute all over the place.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Controlling sharing is tricky in GHC. There are many optimizations that GHC does which can affect sharing (such as inlining, floating things out, etc).

In this case, to answer the question why the SPECIALIZE pragma did not achieve the intended effect, let's look at the Core of the B module, in particular of the `bar` function:

```
Rec {
bar_xs
bar_xs = : x1_r3lO bar_xs
end Rec }

bar1 = $w!! bar_xs 10000000
--     ^^^ this repeats the computation. bar_xs is just repeat 1

bar =
  case trace $fCostlyi2 bar1 of _ { I# x_aDm -> I# (+# x_aDm 2) }
  --         ^^^ this is just the "costly!" string
```

That didn't work as we wanted. Instead of reusing `costly`, GHC decided to just inline the `costly` function.

So we have to prevent GHC from inlining costly, or the computation will be duplicated. How do we do that? You might think adding a `{-# NOINLINE costly #-}` pragma would be enough, but unfortunately specialization without inlining don't seem to work together well:

```
A.hs:13:3: Warning:
    Ignoring useless SPECIALISE pragma for NOINLINE function: ‘$ccostly’
```

But there is a trick to convince GHC to do what we want: we can write `costly` in the following way:

```
instance Num i => Costly i where
  -- an expensive (but non-recursive) computation
  costly = memo where
    memo :: i
    memo = trace "costly!" $ (repeat 1) !! 10000000
    {-# NOINLINE memo #-}
  {-# SPECIALIZE instance Costly Int #-}
-- (this might require -XScopedTypeVariables)
```

This allows us to specialize `costly`, will simultanously avoiding the inlining of our computation.

Comment: Outstanding!  I had tried the memo trick, and NOINLINE with SPECIALIZE (only to get the same error), but hadn't thought to combine them in this way.  This trick will work for some of my global values, but for others I can't SPECIALIZE because I only know the concrete types at the topmost application module.  Is there any hope for that case?

Comment: @ChrisPeikert I haven't checked, but maybe inlining `costly` could achieve the same effect as specialization in this case?

Comment: Right, inlining is the opposite of what I want (i.e., sharing).

Comment: @ChrisPeikert I don't think this is possible. If GHC doesn't know in advance which types the function should be memoized for, there is no way to make the appropriate "top-level memos" that store the memoized value. The only way this could work is if you inlined all functions using `costly` and then somehow arranged for all the memos to be floated out and eliminated by CSE. I doubt that this would work reliably though ...

Comment: Or alternatively, get GHC to auto-specialize costly and CSE all the specializations of `memo` for the same type.